# Additional css file in wordpress not linking through a functions.php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to link my css file to WordPress through a functions.php file.  I am not getting any errors but my page isn't showing up styled at all.  Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function my_own_styles() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio_theme', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/css/portfolio.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_own_styles()' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When delcaring a function in the `add_action` function you don't need to use the `()`, just the name of the function. See how your code should look below.

```
<?php

function my_own_styles() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio_theme', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/css/portfolio.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_own_styles' );

?>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I totally didn't see that!  But unfortunately it is still not linked.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @SeanFF I am not sure what else to suggest as that should work. The only other thing I can suggest is that the file doesn't exist in the themes css directory. Do you get any errors when you look at your browser developer console?

Comment: No, Nothing at all.  That's the frustrating part.  I wish I had errors in there.  They would be a big help right now.  Well, Thanks so much for that () catch!  Truly appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a child theme - which I assume you are when you're making changes such as adding CSS and changing functions.php - then you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` instead of `get_template_directory_uri`, i.e.

```
function my_own_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio_theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/css/portfolio.css' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_own_styles' );
```

`get_template_directory_uri()` returns the path to the current theme *unless a child them is being used*. In that case it returns the path to the *parent* theme.

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri` returns the path to the current theme *even if it is a child theme*.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  But for some reason it still isn't linked.  What else could be missing?  I can't seem to find out what's wrong.

Comment: @SeanFF Can you check the generated HTML and see 1. if a link for portfolio.css is being added (it might just be using the wrong url) and 2.if it's being added, is it before or after your themes style.css? Also, can you update your question to include all your `wp_enqueue_scripts` (i.e. style.css etc)